# Authentication between a logic app and webhook

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have created an Azure function (generic webhook) and I am calling the webhook from a Logic App. This all works successfully however I want to add security so I have enabled authentication on the function app (which contains the webhook function) but now my logic app fails on the step that calls the webhook due to an authorization error. Presumably I need to add some authorization information (client id etc?) into the logic app but I am unsure how to do this?

This is the workflow of the logic app: [image: logic app]

And this is where I have enabled authenticationin the function app which contains the webhook: [image: authentication]

Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: Won't simple authorization based on `code` in URL be sufficient for you?

Comment: You mean setting the azure function to "Function" level security so that calling it requires a code parameter in the url? Is that generally considered sufficient security? I thought turning authorization/authentication on in the azure function would provide a higher level of security that would be considered better practice?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I can't be affirmative about "sufficient security", but unless you expose `code` somewhere, it should be enough for normal scenarios